# How to check if user subscription has expired by comparing if maturity date has passed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, datetime, mongoose

I am currently working on a web app where subscriptions have maturity date, I currently have a middleware that checks if current date equals to the maturity date.

```
  const userdate = user.subscription.maturityDate
            .toString()
            .slice(0, 15);

          const day = new Date().toString().slice(0, 15);

          if (userdate === day) {
            user.isDue = true;
            user.save();
            req.flash(
              "succes",
              "Your current plan has expired please make a withdrawal"
            );
            res.send("Your current plan has expired please make a withdrawal");
```

The problem with the logic is that it only works when todays date is equal to the maturity date, but I want to check if the maturity date has passed. I have tried using a function that checks if the date is in the past but its not working.

```
var dateInPast = function (firstDate, secondDate) {
                      if (
                        firstDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) <=
                        secondDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
                      ) {
                        return true;
                      }

                      return false;
                    };
                    dateInPast(userdate, day);
```

Can someone please point out what am doing wrong.

Comment: Define “not working”.